# Best practice. Make iOS app universal with supporting iOS 5, iOS 6 and iOS 7 UI

Tags: ios, ios7, uistoryboard

I suppose that I can make it using different storyboards for the different iOS versions.

Because of differences in UI I will create next storyboards:

- Main_iPhone.storyboard
- Main_iPad.storyboard
- Main_iPhone_iOS7.storyboard
- Main_iPad_iOS7.storyboard

Is this good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT's hard to provide a YES/NO answer without knowing the whole problem, but in my humble opinion I would say yes, that's a fair approach.

Comment: I just want to make sure that I am no the right way. But maybe there are more simpler solution to achieve this. in any case thanks for response.

Comment: also have I can crate view in storyboard that is correspond to UI from  iOS 6, because by the default it is iOS 7 UI with integrated status bar into view?